# How to use Array.from with a XPathResult?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpath

When I use `querySelectorAll`, I can find 138 `td` nodes in my sample document.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td')).length
138
```

When I do the same with XPath, I get no result:

```
Array.from(document.evaluate(".//td", document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)).length
0
```

Although there is at least one match:

```
document.evaluate(".//td", document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().nodeName
"TD"
```

The problem seems to be that `Array.from` can not iterate over a `XPathResult`. Even this returns 0:

```
Array.from(document.evaluate('.', document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)).length
0
```

How to make a `XPathResult` suitable for `Array.from`?

Comment: It's so cumbersome to get the 2nd element. You can't do it in one line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) can convert two types of objects into arrays:

1. Those that are "array-like" that have a `.length` property.
2. Those that implement the iterator protocol and allow you to get all of their elements.

`XPathResult` doesn't do any of these. You could do this by manually iterating over the result and storing the results in an array such as:

```
const nodes = [];
let node = xPathResult.iterateNext();
while (node) {
  nodes.push(node);
  node = xPathResult.iterateNext();
}
```

...but if you're going to loop over the nodes anyway, you can probably do whatever array operations you wanted to do in the loop.

Comment: To avoid duplication and (imo) make it clearer, you could instead do `const nodes = []; let node; while (node = xPathResult.iterateNext()) {nodes.push(node);}`. Too bad you can't just say `while (const node = xPathResult.iterateNext()) {...}` since the value isn't used outside the loop.

Answer (score 5):

Building up on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503000/383868) from [@JamesTheAwesomeDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874170/jamestheawesomedude), you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) if you polyfill the iterator onto XPathResult. This iterator is just a bit better because it can operate on all types of XPathResult:

```
if (!XPathResult.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) XPathResult.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    switch (this.resultType) {
        case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
        case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
            let result;
            while ( (result = this.iterateNext()) != null ) yield result;
            break;
        case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
        case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
            for (let i=0; i < this.snapshotLength; i++) yield this.snapshotItem(i);
            break;
        default:
            yield this.singleNodeValue;
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the existing answer states, this is not "supported" per se, because (for some bizarre reason) [`XPathResult`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult) doesn't support JS' standard [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) at all.

You could always DIY it, I suppose; this would, naturally, work with your use-case, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
function xpr2iter (xpr) {
  // Produce a JavaScript iterator for an *ITERATOR_TYPE XPathResult
  // or a JavaScript iterable for a *SNAPSHOT_TYPE XPathResult
  switch (xpr.resultType) {
    case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
    case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
      return {
        [Symbol.iterator] () {
          var i = 0;
          return {
            next() {
              var node = xpr.snapshotItem(i++);
              return {value: node, done: !node};
            }
          };
        },
        at(i) {
          return xpr.snapshotItem(i) || undefined;
        }
      };
    case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
    case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
      return {
        next() {
          var node = xpr.iterateNext();
          return {value: node, done: !node};
        },
        [Symbol.iterator] () {
          return this;
        },
      };
  }
}


// As an example, pull the top child elements
// -- should just be the <head> and <body>:
let example1_xpr = document.evaluate('/html/*', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);
// -- render into an Array:
let example1_arr = Array.from(xpr2iter(example1_xpr));

// Can be rendered to an array!
console.log("length:", example1_arr.length);
console.log("map demo (e => e.tagName):", example1_arr.map(e => e.tagName));
```

...however, it *also* supports [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) directly without instantiating a whole `Array`:

```js
function xpr2iter (xpr) {
  // Produce a JavaScript iterator for an *ITERATOR_TYPE XPathResult
  // or a JavaScript iterable for a *SNAPSHOT_TYPE XPathResult
  switch (xpr.resultType) {
    case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
    case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
      return {
        [Symbol.iterator] () {
          var i = 0;
          return {
            next() {
              var node = xpr.snapshotItem(i++);
              return {value: node, done: !node};
            }
          };
        },
        at(i) {
          return xpr.snapshotItem(i) || undefined;
        }
      };
    case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
    case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
      return {
        next() {
          var node = xpr.iterateNext();
          return {value: node, done: !node};
        },
        [Symbol.iterator] () {
          return this;
        },
      };
  }
}

let example2_xpr = document.evaluate('/html/*', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);

for( let e of xpr2iter(example2_xpr) ) {
  // It's iterable!
  console.log(e.tagName);
}
```

Therefore, this solution is slightly more general (and it should also use slightly less memory when iterating over obscenely large amounts of nodes without instantiating an `Array`).

---

> I can find 138 `td` nodes in my sample document.

In fact, *juuust* in case this is an A/B problem and you're only trying to find the number of matches, that can be got **directly** by the [`.snapshotLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/snapshotLength) property of non-iterator types (or you can "manually" count an iterator type, if you prefer):

```js
function xpr2iter (xpr) {
  // Produce a JavaScript iterator for an *ITERATOR_TYPE XPathResult
  // or a JavaScript iterable for a *SNAPSHOT_TYPE XPathResult
  switch (xpr.resultType) {
    case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
    case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
      return {
        [Symbol.iterator] () {
          var i = 0;
          return {
            next() {
              var node = xpr.snapshotItem(i++);
              return {value: node, done: !node};
            }
          };
        },
        at(i) {
          return xpr.snapshotItem(i) || undefined;
        }
      };
    case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
    case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
      return {
        next() {
          var node = xpr.iterateNext();
          return {value: node, done: !node};
        },
        [Symbol.iterator] () {
          return this;
        },
      };
  }
}

let example3_xpr = document.evaluate('/html/*', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);

let example3_n = example3_xpr.snapshotLength;

console.log("number of matches:", example3_n);


let example4_xpr = document.evaluate('/html/*', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE);

let example4_n = 0;
for( let e of xpr2iter(example4_xpr) )
  example4_n ++;

console.log("number of matches:", example4_n);
```